# Return type 'Map<String,Dynamic>' isn't a string, as defined by anonymous closure

Tags: dart, flutter

I am trying to create a list using `List<E>.generate(length, generator)` function but it giving an error `The return type Map<String, Dynamic> isn't a string, as defined by anonymous closure.`

Here is the code.

```
List<String> _generateList() {
    return List<String>.generate(20, (i) => {"Hello $i"});
}
```

Error:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
List<String> _generateList() {
    return List<String>.generate(20, (i) => "Hello $i");
}
```

> Removed the curly brackets in the return statement.